# How to bring browse button inside text box in html

Tags: input

**    How to bring browse button inside text-box?
      I have tried many solutions but I could not find.
      Thanks-in-advance**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, if I understand it correctly.
You may want to use a javascript function to do so, or check the Mickael McGrady's solution :
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Indeed, the display of your button/text-box depends on the version of your browser, so you may want to implement a relative button. On my website I did it in javascript which is more elegant, but if you prefer in html only :

```
<div class="fileinputs">
    <input type="file" class="file" />
    <div class="fakefile">
        <input />
        <img src="search.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and css :

```
div.fileinputs {
    position: relative;
}

div.fakefile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

input.file {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity:0 ;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

<div class="fileinputs">
    <input type="file" class="file" />
    <div class="fakefile">
        <input />
        <img src="search.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

(everything is detailled on the website since it's a well-known issue). Hope it helps.